# Implement a publish/subscribe add-in for excel data

Tags: excel, vba, publish-subscribe

I would like to implement an Excel addin which allows me to publish the data in a cell, or subscribe to data and populate that into a cell, along the JMS Publish-Subscribe Model.

Is there any sample code which does that?

Comment: Do you have any code written so far?

Comment: nope, its a blind start for me.

Comment: I would like to do this as well. Some way of having an in-memory process that receives data from the outside world and updates various cells appropriately, and if the user updates any of those cells it then fires that change back to the outside world. All of these cells would not have formulas as such, they would just be updated as and when from the outside (another system) and the inside (user).

Comment: if you were ok using formulas, i would recommend using the excel RTD  function ..this is a good start : http://xlspot.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=71&Itemid=53. I'm still exploring other solutions, but this is all i have for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part (subscription) the RTD function is usually used. Probably [MSDN documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289150) is the best starting point. You will need to build an RTD server (COM automation server) which implements a predefined interface (IRtdServer).

For the first part (publishing) you can try to access messaging layer via VBA and a library usually provided by a vendor (pretty sure that you can do it with Tibco RV). If there is no appropriate library available - you will need to build one.

Comment: thanks, i also stumbled upon RTD, and i am going through it now !